# How to have an exception in regular expression?

Tags: regex

I have a regex that can detect times format like **19:00 PST**, But based on my regex **2021 PST** is detected as a time. I don't wanna detect a date as a time.
Here is my regex:

```
( |^|)\d{1,2}(?:[.:](\d\d))*\s*([aApP][.: ]?[mM][.: ]?|o['’]clock|afternoon)*\s* PST
```

The detection result based on [regex101](https://regex101.com/) is here:

[image]

How can I change this regex to detect **12 PST after bar12PST** but not detect **2021 PST** as a time?

Regext Link :https://regex101.com/r/zy193H/1/

Comment: Can you add your test strings to your question?

Comment: @Alireza I've added an image that contains my test result.

Comment: Adding a `\b` in front of your pattern will solve your problem? https://regex101.com/r/jW5veW/1

Comment: @Alireza That helps but it doesn't match the `bar12 PST` case

Comment: @Alireza Yes, It works on bar12 PST. It's OK but I don't want to detect 21 PST in 2021 PST

Comment: What about just doing this in two steps, first stripping any leading non-numeric characters, then running your regex test. In otherwords first sub `^[^0-9]*`, then you can remove the `( |^|)` from your existing expression and it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the rest of your regex is correct then you just need to trade `( |^|)` for `(^|(?<=\D))`:

```
(^|(?<=\D))\d{1,2}(?:[.:](\d\d))*\s*([aApP][.: ]?[mM][.: ]?|o['’]clock|afternoon)*\s* PST
```

- `(^|(?<=\D))` - guarantee that behind me is the start of a line or not a digit

https://regex101.com/r/LgzGaJ/1

Answer (score 0):

The initial group `( |^|)` is quite nonsensical, but it's not easy to understand what you *wanted* it to mean. Perhaps replace it with `(^|\s|\D)` to match either beginning of line or a space or a non-digit character.

Depending on what you actually want, `\W` might be closer to what you desire (it also doesn't match alphabetics or underscore), but perhaps clarify what the principle should be.

Comment: Thanks for your response! But adding this expression caused detect r12 PST in bar12PST.

Comment: Yeah, it would be useful if you could explain the principle you are hoping to apply here. You could use `\W` instead of `\D` if that's what you actually mean, but again, I'm speculating here.